# How to Use Python to Identify and Report Bad Data Instances?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-analysis, data-quality

This is a general question on if anyone is aware of a library like sklearn which has a function to read data and report back any strange behaviors or quality concerns within the data after getting user input specifying the type of data such as:

- Flat values for an extended period of time (i.e. variance for last N
  time-series records dropping to 0 suddenly)
- Sudden jumping of data    (Value cliff-dropping to 0, and jumping
  back up to normal, or    extremely high rate of change)
- And so on...

Example (Good):

[image: Blockquote]

(Bad - Dropping to 0):

[image]

(Bad - Flat/constant value when non-constant is expected)

[image]

If such a library already exists, I would appreciate if someone could refer me the name so I can avoid "re-inventing the wheel" and see what other analysis methods there might be that I have not thought of to check for.

Comment: I think the term I’ve heard for this is “anomaly detection.” I don’t know if there are any libraries that are focused on that or do that mostly automatically, but I think `IsolationForest` from sklearn might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is enough for me to go off of and do some more research, I'll share my results if I find anything useful after I get out of this rabbit hole!

Comment: Hey! Not sure if you found the solution you're looking for but I created a library in Python here: https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks that basically lets you write and deploy these types of checks with just Python code 
Anomaly Detection Example: https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks/blob/main/examples/general/anomaly_detection/checks/anomaly_detection_check.py